# How to change collapsed code indicator VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, visibility

When I use the Collapse code function in VSCode I get three little dots after the line of code that contains the collapsed code, see image below: 
[image]

How can i change those three little dots to something else lets say something like:
(CONTAINS HIDDEN CODE) and that in bright pink?

Or is this not possible?

Comment: Lot of discussion here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78024  I don't think you can change either the icon or add verbiage w/o futzing with the underlying css yourself.  Lets see if they change the folding icons.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the link! I hope they change it so that we can configure it ourselves :)